# ImageResizer as COM application - permissions issue

Tags: asp-classic, com+, imageresizer

Permissions have been an issue for other users, and I've attempted several possible solutions.

Windows server 2008r2.

In classic ASP the line:*Set c = CreateObject("ImageResizer.Configuration.Config")*

Results in: *Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046' - Permission denied: 'CreateObject'*

So I tried the classic permissions fix: I have set permissions on *C:\Program Files\ImageResizingNet\v3* for Everyone to *Read & Execute*... but no joy.

Seeing that the dll's were "blocked", I a) uninstalled, b) unblocked the .zip, c)installed (as admin), d)gave permissions to Everyone again on the v3 directory.  No joy.

Further research had me checking Component Services... and there I find no 
reference to ImageResizer. (But not sure if it should be there - I'm slightly out of my depth at that point.)

Other research on the exact ASP error code suggests a registration error, so I tried to run: : regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\ImageResizingNet\v3\ImageResizer.dll" *I get: "The module C:\Program Files\ImageResizingNet\v3\ImageResizer.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found."

This may be a red herring, as the log from the install shows that regasm had no problems with ImageResizer.dll:

```
_Copying and registering .\AForge.dll_  
_Copying and registering .\AForge.Imaging.dll_  
_Copying and registering .\AForge.Math.dll_  
_Copying and registering .\AWSSDK.dll_  
_Copying and registering .\FreeImageNET.dll_  
_Copying and registering .\ImageResizer.dll_  
_Types registered successfully_  
_Types registered successfully_  
_Copying and registering .\ImageResizer.Mvc.dll_  
_Types registered successfully_  
_Types registered successfully_
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You Need to make sure IUSER IIS USER have full write permissions to the .dll and the locations where the images are saved.

Comment: Just to make sure, I gave both EVERYONE **and** IUSR full permissions on the dll.  Same error.  - there is no specified destination at this point, as it is the _CreateObject_ that is failing.

Comment: FWIW, no problems with it at all on a local machine running IIS express

Comment: check your site on the server and make sure that the ASP options on IIS are correct.  You may have to click the enable 32 bit applicaitons, and also make sure you are in classic mode for the pool

Comment: 32 bit applications are enabled, pool is in classic mode -

Comment: it its working fine on the local machine but not server its either:
A. a permissions issue (iuser having access to the dll, temp, etc), 
B. web.config on the server is different where imageresizer.dll is not loaded
C. Something to do with App Pool, bitness or ASP classic options on iis

Have you tried the .net version of the image-resizer?  It works fine with classic asp running in the same site.

Comment: The .net version was my work-around - it works a treat. As you suggest, this appears to be very server/app-pool specific, and not worth pursuing.

Comment: I still code in Classic asp around 30% of my time.  I love it, except when it comes to doing something serious, then you need to mix in some .net.  I found the only hiccup is sharing sessions between asp.net / asp, but moved away from Session cookies years ago.    ASP classic does not run as fast, but I still seem to be able to get things done faster in it. 

Glad you found a solution which works foryou.